# How to animate more elements at the same time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to understand how to animate more elemets at the same time in jQuery.

Let's say I have a simplified code like this:

```
var $targetElement = $('#target-element');

var offset = $targetElement.offset();
var width = $targetElement.outerWidth();
var height = $targetElement.outerHeight();

var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
var bodyHeight = $('body').height();

$topHelper.animate({
    height: offset.top
});

$rightHelper.animate({
    top: offset.top,
    width: bodyWidth - offset.left - width,
    height: height
});

$bottomHelper.animate({
    height: bodyHeight - offset.top - height
});

$leftHelper.animate({
    top: offset.top,
    width: offset.left,
    height: height
});
```

Where the `targetElement` is an element somwhere in the body and all those `helpers` are black semitransparent absolutely positioned layers (right on the body) which should get to sorround the *targetElement's* bounding box.

[image: Layers arounding the target element]

The problem is that during the animation I can see tiny (1px - 3px) gaps or overlaps between the animated layers. It's on the edges where the layers shoud be always next to each other. I think it's because I animate 4 elements and every element has its own 'fx' queue. So there are 4 timers and the 'frame refresh' is not at the same time for all of them.

Is it true or am I totally wrong? How can I synchronize animation of more elements?

**EDIT** From comments below:

- Well, I don't understand how to use css animations here. I think they are declarative and I need to animate to a dynamically computed positions.
- `requestAnimationFrame` looks promising, unfortunatelly I need to support IE9.
- I would really appreciate an answer regarding to the jQuery animations. More specifically, are my assumptions about 4 timers right? If yes, is it possible to animate more elements in one 'queue' - that is recompute all 4 element positions in every 'frame repaint' together?

Comment: Animating things with JavaScript has some downsides, for example that it's very slow (so it will not play with smooth 60 fps) and timing isn't accurate.

If you want to look into something new, I suggest learning how to animate using CSS, which is even hardware accelerated in some browsers.

Comment: @narrowtux: You need to learn about `requestAnimationFrame`. :-) Saying JavaScript animations can't keep up with 60fps is just plain wrong. jQuery's animations aren't fast, but that doesn't mean JavaScript animation needs to be slow: [*Myth Busting: CSS Animations vs. JavaScript*](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) In fact, smartly written, they can be *faster* (and get hardware acceleration).

Comment: I strongly recommend to use [`css-transition`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) instead of script animation. [can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). You can detect the browser support with [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/). In that way most of the users will get a smooth animations.

Comment: Thanks for comments. See my updated question.